# Distinguishing form being built for rendering versus submission

Tags: 7, forms

Is there a way to distinguish, inside a form function, that the form is being built to be rendered on the page, as opposed to being re-built as a result of submission?

I would like to use `drupal_set_message()` inside the form function, but only while it's being built for rendering.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the $form_state elements. You'll want to look at 'submitted', 'rebuild', 'cache', 'programmed', etc... depending on your use-case.  You can get a good idea of those elements and what they mean in [drupal_build_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7).  I typically use $form_state['submitted'].

Comment: Thanks. I examined `$form_state` to find differences, and I noticed that the form function gets called *twice* upon submission: one time with the `input` entry empty, and one time with `input` holding the form submission values. The first case was identical to the contents of `$form_state` when the form function is called to render the form, so I still can't tell them apart.

Comment: When a form is being built for submission (as-in presenting the form to the end user), the $form_state['submitted'] = FALSE.  When the form is submitted, the $form_state['submitted'] = TRUE.  Assuming that's your use-case.

Also, if you're trying to evaluate the submitted content you want to use $form_state['values'] and not $form_state['input'].

Comment: Here's a similar question that provides other approaches that may be helpful.  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124814/how-to-call-a-webservices-on-hook-form-form-id-alter-but-not-when-the-form-is-su/125207?noredirect=1

Comment: Thanks for the link. In my use-case, `$form_state['submitted']` is FALSE when the form is being rendered, AND the first time the form function gets called after submission.